# Red Hat OpenShift -- how to install OS package from SSH session into existing app

Tags: ssh, openshift, yum, package-managers

This is my first time deploying an app. I looked into OpenShift and Heroku this morning and decided on the former. I've got my app set up and working except that part of my app uses a OS package that I need to install on my OpenShift application server.

I've used `rhc ssh <app>` followed by several attempts to install the package I want using different package managers. It seems like `yum` is the default package manager for OpenShift applications, but I'm unable to use it -- here is the output:

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough information -- I'm not sure what would else would be relevant. Let me know if there's something else necessary to diagnose the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User accounts do not have permissions to install software on the servers using the yum command.  These are shared servers, not a VPS environment. If it is a package that multiple people would be interested in using, you can suggest it at openshift.uservoice.com, or if it is a simple package, you could try compiling it yourself on your gear and install it into your ~/app-root/data directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you tell me a bit more (or link me to a source) about compiling a package into my node app? 

The package in question is [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) -- can I just clone that repository into my main project folder and push the changes to my OpenShift repository without having to do any compiling/building?